# how to not match a particular number at the end of a string in regex perl?

Tags: regex, perl

I have a file that has a list that looks like this:

```
    $ABC01
    $ABC02
    $ABC03
    $ABC04
    $ABC05
```

I want all those strings that are not `$ABC02`. This is a part of a code and before this step I got string ABC recorded in one variable, and the number 02 recorded in other. I basically want all those entries that start with ABC, and end with a 2 digit number apart from `02`.

I tried this but it is not working:

```
/^\$ABC[^02]$/
```

What is the correct regex to be used in this case?

Comment: Try this `/^\$ABC\d[^2\D]$/`

Comment: I imagine that you have fabricated this data as something sufficiently close to the real data to illustrate your question. But it can be difficult to generate something that is properly representative and you need to be careful. For instance, are there really blank spaces at the start of each line?

Comment: Yeah, if there are spaces, just add `\h*` after `^`, `/^\h*\$ABC(?!02$)[0-9]+$/`

Answer (score 2):

What your regex currently does is find "$ABC" followed by one digit. You need to split that `[^02]` into matching 2 characters like this.

```
/^\$ABC[^0][^2]$/
```

...but...that will also match strings that have non-digits at the end. So rather than using what you don't want to find - put in what you do want to find.

```
/^\$ABC([1-9][0-9]|0[013-9])$/
```

This will look for either 1 to 9 followed by any digit or 0 followed by any digit except for a 2. You can replace the `(...)` with `(?:...)` if you don't want a capture group.

Answer (score 2):

Note that `[^02]` is a negated character class that matches any character other than `0` and `2`, and it does not have to be a digit, BTW.

You may use `(?!02$)` negative lookahead after `C` to avoid matching strings that end with `02`, but end with any other number (including `0210`,etc.):

```
/^\$ABC(?!02$)[0-9]+$/
```

See [this regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/BzE7TJ/2)

If you do not want to match numbers after `C` that *start with `02`, remove `$` from the lookahead:

```
/^\$ABC(?!02)[0-9]+$/
```

See [another regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/BzE7TJ/3).

Answer (score 0):

It looks like you just need to eliminate one specific line from your file. Rather than writing a fancy regex pattern that matches `$ABC` followed by anything but `02`, you can simply use the language to discard the given string. Something like `print if not /\$ABC02/`

In a Perl one-line command, this checks whether the whole line matches the value and ignores it if so

```
perl -ne 'print unless /^\$ABC02$/' myfile
```